# summation of values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

There is a pandas dataframe with two columns 'key' and 'value'.
I want summation of values corresponding to the rows with key in range(key-3,key-1) to be put in a new column 'new_value' in the original dataframe.
for eg:

df:

```
key  value
1     2
2     1
3     1
5     1
7     1
```

output would be:

```
key value new_value
1   2     0
2   1     2
3   1     3
5   1     2
7   1     1
```

Comment: What did you try so far and did not work ? Show us your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at this :

```
In [52]: df
Out[52]: 
   key  value
0    1      2
1    2      1
2    3      1
3    5      1
4    7      1

In [53]: df['new_value'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[(df['key'] >= x['key'] - 3) & (df['key'] <= x['key'] - 1)]['value'].sum(), axis=1)

In [54]: df
Out[54]: 
   key  value  new_value
0    1      2          0
1    2      1          2
2    3      1          3
3    5      1          2
4    7      1          1
```

I'm using [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to compute the new value for each row.

Comment: what if the input is like this:
key value
1      2
1      2
1      2
2       1
2       1
3       1
5       1
7       1
output required:
key value new_value
1     2       0
1     2       0
1     2       0
2     1       2
2     1       2
3     1       3
5     1       2
7     1       1

Comment: @starlord you just need to put a `drop_duplicates()` before the `sum()`.